# pynag with python3.6 TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, nagios

I'm trying to read my nagios config data as follows:

```
pynag.Model.cfg_file = "path_to_nagios.cfg"
all_hosts = pynag.Model.Host.objects.all"
```

This returns an error
TypeError: endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes

From what I've read so far, it seems that it's related to how files are opened in python3
Do you know how to correct this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was in the library code. The def parse_file() is opening files as 'rb'. The reason this is an error in Python 3 and not Python 2 is that Python 2 treats bytes as an alias or synonym for str. It doesn't make a distinction between byte strings and unicode strings as is done in Python 3.

In pynag/Parsers/**init**.py changed

`lines = open(self.filename, 'rb').readlines()`

to

`lines = open(self.filename, 'r').readlines()`